# extend functionality of addDocumentListener

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, documentlistener

I've a text field which extends `javax.swing.JTextField` and also have document listener like this

```
public class MyTetField extends javax.swing.JTextFiled{
     public MyTextField(){
          super();
          // Document listener to check mandatory functionality
          getDocument().addDocumentListener(new javax.swing.event.DocumentListener() {
            /**
             * If the text is changed then this event will be fired.
             */
            public void changedUpdate(javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent e) {
            }
            /**
             * If some value is removed then this event is fired.
             */
            public void removeUpdate(javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent e) {
            }
            /**
             * If some value is auto set, this event will be called
             * @param e The value change event
             */
            public void insertUpdate(javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent e) {
                if (getText().trim().equals("")){
                    setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(java.awt.Color.RED));
                }else{
                    setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(java.awt.Color.GRAY));
                }
            }
        });
     }
}
```

Now I want another text field say `MyTextField1`extending `MyTextField` which should have this mandatory check and also to get some information from DB after checking mandatory field and if some value is given. I do not want to write the same document listener code in that. Is it possible to extend document listener which we added in `MyTextField` OR should I go for focus listener?

Comment: As @Robin already mentioned: don't extend JSomething, they are designed to be _used_ as-are. And no, a focus listener _never_ (to first approximation) is a solution, it's far too low level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There is no need to extend `JTextField` for what you are doing. Most of the times, there is no need to extend the Swing components.
2. What your listener does in your `MyTextField` class looks remarkably similar to what a `JFormattedTextField` does. You might want to consider using that class instead
3. To actually answer your question, you can extend your `MyTextField` class and just add another `DocumentListener` which does some extra checks. You will keep your original functionality since the super class will add its own `DocumentListener`

Comment: full ack for the first, nitpicking on the others: 2) afair, a formatted text field doesn't change the border ;-) 3) technically correct, but not recommended (piling up listeners through the inheritance hierarchy can have weird interference effects)

Comment: @kleopatra I thought every Swing programmer has an improved version of JFormattedTextfield in his/her arsenal which improved user feedback

Answer (score 3):

From your description, I assume that you want a validate-with-visual-feedback-on-document-change where the exact validation rule is the variable. If so, break it down into

- a validation interface which checks a string value
- a controller which uses that validation to decide if/how to decorate a given textComponent based on the validation result

some pseudo code

```
public interface TextPredicate {
     public boolean isValid(String text);
}

public class NotEmptyTextPredicate implements TextPredicate {
     // imlemented to return true/false for not/empty text
}

public class OnChangeValidator  {
     private TextPredicate predicate;
     private JTextComponent textComponent;
     private DocumentListener listener;

     public OnChangeValidator(JTextComponent component, TextPredicate predicate) {
          // assign and register the listener
          this.predicate = ....
          ...
          this.listener = create...
          component.getDocument().addDocumentListener(listener); 
     }

     protected void validate() {
         decorate(predicate.isValid(textComponent.getText())
     }

     protected void decorate(boolean valid) {
        if (valid) {
           // set normal visual properties
        } else {
          // set error visual properties
     }   


     protected DocumentListener createDocumentListener() {  
        DocumentListener l = new DocumentListener() {
          @Override
          public void insertUpdate(...) {
              validate();
          }

          @Override
          public void removeUpdate(...) {
              validate();
          }
        };
        return l;
     }
}
```